# How to fill an ellipse shape?

Tags: c++, c, algorithm, geometry, ellipse

I have a function in C++ which draws an ellipse. Now I want to add a fill option to that ellipse. How do I do that? I tried using the flood fill algorithm, but it does not work correctly when the surface already contains paintings.

Here is my current algorithm:

```
const double TwoPI = ( PI * 2 );
const double Step = ( PI / 180.0f );

for( double i = 0;  i < TwoPI;  i += Step )
{
    float x_offset = ( radiusX * cos( (float) i ) );
    float y_offset = ( radiusY * sin( (float) i ) );

    int x = int( a_X + x_offset );
    int y = int( a_Y + y_offset );

    if( prevX == -1  &&  prevY == -1 )
        Plot( x, y, color );
    else
        Line( prevX, prevY, x, y, color );
}
```

Comment: What library are you using? `C++` doesn't have a graphics library as defined by the standard. Are you referring to OpenGL, etc?

Comment: Why are you not filling as you draw it?

Comment: @CoryKramer: For an algorithm question, that's pretty irrelevant. Obviously, with a real graphic library, the answer would be "use the provided `DrawEllipse` function", but that would have been the answer already for the non-filled ellipse.

Comment: @CoryKramer I am using SDL for drawing purposes. But my question is more about the algorithm.

Comment: Flood-fill does work correctly, for _its_ definition of correctly. The problem is that it fills any region, including donuts, and therefore won't fill the interior of a donut. It stops filling at any edge, including interior edges. Figuring out what is and is not an interior edge is surprisingly hard, though. Be glad you're doing it in 2D. 3D printing has to do it in 3D where it's [generally impossible](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orientability)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, one idea could be to just traverse half the circle, and instead compute points that are symmetrically placed around i.e. the y axis. Then draw a horizontal line between them, filling in all the pixels.

Comment: So instead of using the `Line()` function directly, I would use it to calculate all pixels between two points on one axis?

Comment: @Zoq: No, the idea is that you _do_ use Line, but you draw a line from (-X, Y) to (X,Y). If you'd then use alternate colors for every line, you'd see a horizontal stripe pattern. (But with your _fixed angular_ step size, many of these lines would overlap. You'd be better of taking a _fixed vertical_ step)

Comment: I understand. When the ellipse is small, they do overlap, but when the ellipse is large, they will be far from one another

Comment: @MSalters How do I use vertical steps?

Comment: @Z0q: `for(double y = radiusY; y >-radiusY; i- = 1.0)`. Getting `x` as function of `y` takes a `sqrt`, that's easier then trying to use an `arcsin` followed by a `cos`.

Answer (score 0):

You travel in both directions and drow a line from edge to edge
Something like this:
I did not try to run it.It's just the idea.Its supposed to paint a filled circle.

```
const double TwoPI = ( PI * 2 );
const double Step = ( PI / 180.0f );
double start=0;
for( double i = 0;  i < TwoPI;  i += Step )
{
    float x_offset = ( radiusX * cos( (float)start+ i ) );
    float y_offset = ( radiusY * sin( (float) start+i ) );

    float x2_offset = ( radiusX * cos( (float)start - i ) );


    int x = int( a_X + x_offset );
    int x2 = int( a_X + x_offset );
    int y = int( a_Y + y_offset );


    Line( x, y, x2, y, color );
}
```

Comment: what is a_X and a_Y?